# Error con NG-select en angular 8

Tags: angular

Estoy tratando de crear un select con buscador, los datos vienen de una api. 
El problema es que al clickear el combobox para comenzar a escribir, devuelve una serie de errores por consola, que no estoy pudiendo detectar.

Este es mi codigo en el html:

```
<ng-select [items]="localidades"
                                #select
                                bindLabel="locality_name"
                                dropdownPosition="auto"
                                bindValue="locality_id"
                                labelForId="album"
                                placeholder="Seleccione localidad"
                                [virtualScroll]="true"
                                formControlName="LocalityID">
                            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="localidad" let-search="searchTerm">
                                <div><span>Title: </span><span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">{{ localidad.locality_name}}</span></div>
                                <small><b>Id:</b> {{ localidad.locality_id }} | <b>UserId:</b></small>
                            </ng-template>
                        </ng-select>
```

"localidades" es mi array con datos, que intento recorrer para mostrar las opciones. 
Al clickear el buscador, me dice que locality_name y locality_id no están definidos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy accediendo mal a ellos?
Hice un console.log de mi array de localidades y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así cargo las localidades de la api:

```
  // BUSCAMOS CIUDADES
 ngOnInit() {

    this.servicio.getCities()
    .subscribe( 
      result => {      
              this.localidades = result.data;
              console.log(this.localidades);
          },
      error => {
          //console.log(<any>error);
        }
      );
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cómo cargas esos datos desde el API? Es probable que trates de acceder a sus datos antes de que hayan sido recibidos. Con únicamente el código que has compartido va a ser complicado ayudarte.

Comment: Oscar, añado la llamada a la api a la publicación. Te aclaro que está en un ngOnInit, se invoca un servicio que carga las localidades en un array "localidades", ese mismo intento mostrar en el html. Adjunto codigo. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Y el valor por defecto de `localidades`? Trato de reproducir tu problema en este enlace: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-sun-ti5u4

Comment: Sigo tratando de reproducir tu problema en el enlace proporcionado. Ahora he simulado un retardo de 2 segundos en obtener los datos del API (para simular una conexión muy lenta o un sitio web muy cargado) y sigue sin producirse tu problema. ¿Podrías compartir el código completo en alguna plataforma como github (como repositorio o como gist) o similar? Gracias.

Comment: Gracias Oscar. Checkee tu código y me di cuenta del error. El problema era como venían los datos de la api. Ya que probé con el array que creaste de localidades y funcionó perfecto. Era cuestión de como acceder a esos datos.

Comment: Entoces creo que recortaste demasiado la captura de pantalla con la salida del `console.log()`. Me alegra que hayas solucionado el problema.

Answer (score 2):

del lado HTML asegúrate de que los datos `localidades` estén cargados.

Y para ello puedes agregar una condición con `*ngIf`

```
<ng-select *ngIf="localidades" [items]="localidades" ...
```

Comment: Esto es más bien un comentario que una respuesta. En los comentarios podrás leer que el problema fue otro diferente.